# Javascript Not Passing Value to Function

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables

Hi I am trying to pass 3 values into some Javascript. This works for the first function. All values are found to be correct here......

```
function handleClick(cb,colum,id) {
  if (cb.checked == true){
     var checked = 1;
  } else {
     var checked = 0;
  }
  sendHddToPHP2(checked,column,id);
}
```

But once the second function is called I get nothing....

```
function sendHddToPHP2(editableObj,column,id) {
  window.alert(editableObj);
  $.ajax({
          url: "update/hdd.php",
          type: "POST",
          data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj+'&id='+id,
          success: function(data){
                   $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                   }
  });
}
```

I added the alert to check if the variable was present and it didn't run. I can't see any typos and my knowledge isn't that great on Javascript. Is there something I have missed?

Comment: Define "nothing".  Do you get anything in your error console?  Have you put debugger statements within your `success` callback?  Have you added an `error` callback?  Do you get *any* errors or anything to go on?

Comment: Note that you could also condense it down to a single line by using a ternary operation:
`var checked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo: "colum" in the argument list.

Also, seems like you want to access the check box later in the Ajax callback, that will fail since you're trying to reference it via the "editableObj" value of the checkbox rather than the element.

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I didn't see it, thanks. I thought I had done this correctly

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want your function to be like this:

```
function handleClick(cb,colum,id) {
  var checked = (cb.checked)?1:0;//same as(cb.checked==true)1:0
  sendHddToPHP2(checked,column,id);
}
```

but are you sure you want to return a 1 or 0? because in the second function you will be using `$(1).css("background","#FDFDFD"); 
$(0).css("background","#FDFDFD");`